# Как начать понимать спецификации JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, спецификация, модули

Проблема в том, что я изучаю Java Script по мануалам и статьям, самостоятельно. Использую пока его просто для того, чтобы сделать тривиальные задачи. Сейчас решил сделать конструктор на базе [Wijmo](http://demos.wijmo.com/5/PureJS/TreeViewIntro/TreeViewIntro/#tvDragDrop1), там есть два блока Drag&Drop, в первом (верхнем) блоке находятся начальные элементы, которые парсятся с json (это я уже сделал, было не сложно), но мне надо взять собранную пользователем информацию со второго блока (нижнего) и спарсить её в новый json.

Проблема в том, что я начал читать спецификации и без примером не понимаю, как правильно записать их в коде, чтобы скрипт давал мне, то что обещает спецификация. Я начал искать парсер и там тоже ничего не понял.

Помогите разъяснить или укажите на статьи где объяснялось бы как понимать спецификации такого рода.

Вот пример того , что я не могу понять как записывать в коде:

```
getNode(item: any): TreeNode
```

Ссылки на спецификации:

https://github.com/andrejewski/himalaya/blob/master/text/ast-spec-v1.md

http://demos.wijmo.com/5/Angular/WijmoHelp/WijmoHelp/topic/wijmo.nav.TreeView.Class.html

Comment: было бы не плохо увидеть пример того, что у тебя сейчас есть, и что конкретно не получается

Comment: @Grundy , вот архив с тем , что есть сейчас: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QB2iDuPUO-Hior5xYW5vDLzo9GiedMFg

Comment: @Grundy как и писал ранее , не могу понять спецификацию Wijmo и не могу спарсить дерево которое формирует пользователь в нижней форме.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Описание классов](http://demos.wijmo.com/5/Angular/WijmoHelp/WijmoHelp/topic/wijmo.nav.TreeView.Class.html) приведено для компонентов `Angular` и, соответственно, они описывают не javascript, а typescript.

Однако, кроме декларации метода, нужно смотреть его описание, в котором описано что возвращает метод, и какие параметры принимает.

Для примера: [`getNode(item: any): TreeNode`](http://demos.wijmo.com/5/Angular/WijmoHelp/WijmoHelp/topic/wijmo.nav.TreeView.Class.html#getNode)

Описание метода: *Gets the TreeNode object representing a given data item.* (Получает объект типа `TreeNode`, у которого значение [свойства `dataItem`](http://demos.wijmo.com/5/Angular/WijmoHelp/WijmoHelp/topic/wijmo.nav.TreeNode.Class.html#dataItem) содержит значение `item`)

Параметры: `item: any` - *The data item to look for.* (данные которые ищутся)
Возвращаемое значение: объект типа `TreeNode`.

Для примера: если в `itemsSource`, если объект `var el = {header: 'header'}`, то вызов `tree.getNode(el)` вернет `TreeNode`, в которой содержится искомый элемент.

---

Что касается получение обновленного `json`. Актуальный массив для второго дерева можно получить с помощью [метода `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) примененного к свойству [`nodes`](http://demos.wijmo.com/5/Angular/WijmoHelp/WijmoHelp/topic/wijmo.nav.TreeView.Class.html#nodes) и получения у каждого узла первого уровня [свойства `dataItem`](http://demos.wijmo.com/5/Angular/WijmoHelp/WijmoHelp/topic/wijmo.nav.TreeNode.Class.html#dataItem), в котором хранится конкретный объект.

Пример:

```js
var t = {
  header: 'Custom'
}
// create trees to drag/drop between
var tvDragDrop1 = new wijmo.nav.TreeView('#tvDragDrop1', {
  displayMemberPath: 'header',
  childItemsPath: 'items',
  allowDragging: true,
  dragOver: dragOverBetweenTrees,
  itemsSource: [t, {
      header: 'Item 1.1'
    },
    {
      header: 'Item 1.2'
    },
    {
      header: 'Item 1.3'
    },
  ]
});
var tvDragDrop2 = new wijmo.nav.TreeView('#tvDragDrop2', {
  displayMemberPath: 'header',
  childItemsPath: 'items',
  allowDragging: true,
  dragOver: dragOverBetweenTrees,
  itemsSource: []
});

// allow drag/drop between tvDragDrop1 and tvDragDrop2
function dragOverBetweenTrees(s, e) {
  var t1 = e.dragSource.treeView,
    t2 = e.dropTarget.treeView;
  if (t1 == tvDragDrop1 || t1 == tvDragDrop2) {
    if (t2 == tvDragDrop1 || t2 == tvDragDrop2) {
      e.cancel = false;
    }
  }
}

function getjson() {
  var nodes = tvDragDrop2.nodes;
  var data = nodes.map(function recursiveNodes(node) {
    return node.dataItem;
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
}
```

```css
.short {
  min-height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- latest Wijmo version -->
<script src="https://cdn.grapecity.com/wijmo/5.latest/controls/wijmo.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.grapecity.com/wijmo/5.20181.436/controls/wijmo.nav.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.grapecity.com/wijmo/5.latest/styles/wijmo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="short" id="tvDragDrop1"></div>
<div class="short" id="tvDragDrop2"></div>

<input type="button" onclick="getjson()" value="click" />
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за вашу помощь. До того как вы ответили я к счастью сам смог разобраться в проблеме. Но ваше решение парсинга элементов оказалось куда совершеннее. Я начал парсить элементы с помощью : `JSON.stringify(tvDragDrop2.itemsSource)` , но к сожалению не всегда получал актуальные данные дерева , до сих пор не могу понять , почему оно то выдавало правильные данные , то не обновляло их вовсе. Может вы на этот вопрос тоже знаете ответ ? Буду рад , если вы сможете мне ответить .

Comment: кстати в вашем , как и моём варианте парсинга есть один недочёт (он больше недочёт модуля , но всё же) Когда мы вкладываем элемент друг в друга , а потом , вынимаем его обратно , то в массиве появляется такой элемент :  `,"items":[]` , я его устраняю с помощь: `.replace(/\,\"items\"\:\[\]/, "");` не знаю , на сколько это грамотное решение , но оно работает )

Comment: добавил флаг global : `.replace(/\,\"items\"\:\[\]/g, "");`

Comment: @GreenBird, _.itemsSource_ у них сохраняется ссылка на массив, который был передан в самом начале. Я не совсем понял как именно он обновляется. Удалять `items` нужно не после перевода в строку, а во время, например используя [параметр `replacer` в JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Example_of_using_replacer_parameter)